# DIstinct values and id's on selection in select box

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

It may sound a little easy but I am not getting any clues on this. I want to populate a select box with distinct values in a column and I need id's of them too. I am making an ajax request on selecting a value from the drop-down which takes id of selected value and processes it further. Currently, I have my query as shown below but using this the select box options get empty.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT rpp_id,DISTINCT rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no  FROM tbl_regn_prescribed_parameters where rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no  != 0 GROUP BY rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no" ) ;
                  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){  
                     $rpp_id    = $row['rpp_id'];
                     $rpp_bulkbatch_no    = $row['rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no'] ;
             echo "<option value=" . $rpp_id . ">" . $rpp_bulkbatch_no . "</option>";
```

Can i know what should be the proper query for this? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  Maybe you can include some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: Actually I have `rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no` in a table and an auto-increment `rpp_id` with each. On selecting a `rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no` I want to obtain its `rpp_id` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hence resolved with this.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT rpp_id, rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no FROM tbl_regn_prescribed_parameters where rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no  != 0 GROUP BY rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no" ) ;
              while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){  
                 $rpp_id    = $row['rpp_id']; 
                 $rpp_bulkbatch_no    = $row['rpp_regn_bulkbatch_no'] ;
         echo "<option value=" . $rpp_id . ">" . $rpp_bulkbatch_no . "</option>";     

                   }
```